# Parse UTF8 json file in swift not work correctly with SwiftyJson

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I tried to load UTF8 JSON file in swift and I received response in `NSData`. Then I converted it to `NSString` by:

```
let responseString = NSString(data: myNSdata!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let json = JSON(responseString)
print(json["now"].string)
print(json.string)
```

First print show nil but second print show file correctly but there is `\` char before each `"` and I think this is the reason. Please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to make a string to init `JSON()`, do it with the data:

```
let json = JSON(data: myNSdata!)
```